# How to use `npm` in bundled electron app?

Tags: npm, electron

While I run `npm install` in bundled electron app, it throws an error: `/bin/sh: npm: command not found`.

then I use `shelljs` to check if `npm` command is available by `shell.which('npm')`, it returns `false`.

will `npm` be bundled into the final package? if `npm` is not bundled in electron application, how can I install node modules from electron app?

Answer (score 0):

Packages such as [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) handle this for you. If there are native modules that npm cannot install, you'll have to follow some of [their recommendations](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#how-to-install-native-modules) to get those set up. Most apps don't require these extra steps though.

I've got an [electron template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) that uses electron-builder and implements best-security practices for electron apps, in case you need an application template.